# Will this return string every time?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

```
foreach(Info::countries() as $country):
```

Countries method in Info class returns the array of countries. My question, will countries method be executed one time or the amount of countries there are?

Because this:

```
for($i = 0; count($array); $i++)
```

would count array many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 time.

It is the same as doing this:

```
$countries = Info::countries();
foreach ($countries as $country) ...
```

Comment: What about for($i = 0; count($array); $i++)? Why it counts array many times?

Comment: @hey: Because that part of a `for` loop is the *condition* and that's how a `for` loop is defined to work.

Answer (score 0):

It will call it once only and get an iterator.

If that is a returned array, it will be iterated over and then discarded, and free'd when GC decides to do it.